# Powerpivot - Flag whether row value in one column exists in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

All I need to do is create a calculated column that flags whether or not the row value in one column exists anywhere in another column within the same table.

```
  id | Code 1        | Code 2         | Attempted results
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | 1095829       | 1093895        | Y               
   2 | 1093895       | 1838949        | N               
   3 | 1095289       | 1093910        | Y               
   4 | 1093910       | 1840193        | N
```

So essentially, is Code 1 found anywhere in the code 2 column

Comment: Are you looking for an Excel formula solution or a Power Pivot / DAX formula solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the formula below under Attempted result

> `=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$5,C2)>0,"Y","N")`

where

1. B2:B5 is the first column range **(Code-1)**
2. C2 the first value in column 2 (Row Value) **(Code-2)**

and you can drag it down but keep absolute value for the first column `$B$2:$B$5`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a DAX solution, I would add a Calculated Column using something like:

`=IF(ISBLANK(LOOKUPVALUE([Code 2],[Code 2],[Code 1])),"Y","N")`

Meaning: Lookup [Code 2] for rows where [Code 2] = [Code 1].  If the result is blank, return Y otherwise N.